# jQuery Uncaught TypeError: $(...).autocomplete is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, autocomplete

I have the following files

```
<link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
<link href="css/style2.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="css/default.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="css/index.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="js/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

That was working fine but when I added other JS files like DateTimepicker then my autocomplete function stops working.

```
<script src="js/jquery.datetimepicker.full.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link href="css/jquery.datetimepicker.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

Error:

> Uncaught TypeError: $(...).autocomplete is not a function

Comment: Add the jquery code where its failing so We can help you out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is because you're including two versions of jQuery. The first one has jQueryUI methods added to it. The second one then overwrites the first. Remove the last jQuery `script` include.

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<!-- REMOVE THIS >> <script src="js/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script> -->
<script src="js/jquery.datetimepicker.full.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/jquery.datetimepicker.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style2.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/default.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css" />
```

Comment: Thank you for coming to the rescue. I spent hours figuring out what I was doing wrong. I was including jQuery at two places. I removed the one at one place after jquery-ui.js. Thanks for explaining the reason for the error.

Answer (score 0):

seems like you have added `jQuery library` twice.

keep it only once.

Either this one `<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>` or `<script src="js/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>`