# clientlibs.min.js: Uncaught TypeError: $(...).autocomplete is not a function

Tags: autocomplete, aem, jquery-ui-autocomplete

Created a simple search component in AEM and added following code in its JSP.
Also added autocomplete plugin and jquery plyugin file in clientlib node. But getting error "autocomplete is not a function" every time I try to run the page with this component. Is it not compatible to be used with AEM?
Using AEM 6.0 SP2

```
<% @include file="/libs/foundation/global.jsp"%>
<cq:includeClientLib categories="jquerysamples" />

<html>
<head>
<script>
$(function() {
            var availableTutorials = [
               "ActionScript",
               "Boostrap",
               "C",
               "C++",
            ];
            $( "#searchInput" ).autocomplete({
               source: availableTutorials
            });
         });
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="formDiv">
        <form id="form" >
            <input type="text" id="searchInput" name="searchbox">
            <div id="searchResults"/>
        </form>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend understanding how browsers parse HTML documents.  http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/internals/howbrowserswork/#HTML_Parser is an introductory resource.

- You have a JS script tag inside the head of your document. (this is immediate parse & execute)
- there is a `cq:includeClientLib` outside of the document.  I don't believe HTML5 behavior defines how this should behave.
- no jQuery document onLoad is defined, so the browser attempts to run JavaScript before any DOM has been built.

I recommend:

- Try moving the `cq:includeClientLib` inside the head.
- Use the HTML5 doctype `<!doctype html>`.  This should "kick" browsers into a consistent parsing mode (especially avoiding IE's myriad of quirks modes).
- Move your script block to just inside the end of by body.  Even better, wrap the JS with an onload handler to cause the JS to run AFTER the HTML has been parsed & the DOM has been built.

Comment: Alternately, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36455911/jquery-uncaught-typeerror-autocomplete-is-not-a-function?rq=1 answers the same basic question, but from outside AEM/JSP's.

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution. It was not binding the jquery-ui plugin. I added dependency of "cq:includeClientLib" for plugin folder to the js file I was using for autocomplete. It is working like a charm now.